# The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context error after opening WPF project with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

After opening my WPF .NET 4.5 project in Visual Studio 2015, every view yields the following error in my error view:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>
> Error CS0103  The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

However, the project builds just fine and tells me it's got 0 errors. Even with "Warnings as Errors" in my build configuration being enabled.

ReSharper tells me I should implement missing members `Connect` and `InitializeComponent` in my view:

[image]

After doing so, the build error went away and method stubs containing `throw new NotImplementedExceptions()` are being entered, clearly made by R#.

What should I do with this? Do I need to implement both methods? If yes, how? Is there any documentation about this - what seems to be a - breaking change?

Comment: i actually can reproduce this bug. But after creating new project in the new solution from VS2015 there is no error and both methods seems to be implemented. I guess some reference error ?

Comment: @LightCZ Did you try to compare the solution files before and after adding a new project? Any differences?

Comment: Ah i meant when you create totally new solution. I still dont know how to fix existing project. same error. Wierd that internet is silent about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while moving a WinRT 8.1 project to UWP. In my case I renamed the UWP App.Xaml (+ .cs etc.) to OrigApp.Xaml and then added in the old App.Xaml. However, the Build Action on both files was still set to 'ApplicationDefinition'. Changing the build action on the renamed App.Xaml to None , or just deleting it :), resolved the issue for me.